# Java: Finding which lines an import (package or relevant Jar) is used

Tags: java, dependencies, dependency-management, static-code-analysis

I want to know which line(s) are using a given import in a Java file.

Imagine having this Java file. How can we tell which lines are using a `method` or `constant` provided by each import (their package). Only methods or constants [that are listed on Oracle Java API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or jars.

```java
 # SomeFileYouReceived.java

package xxxxx;

import java.util.Stack;

public class SomeFileYouReceived ... 
{
   ...
   private Stack fMethodStack= new Stack();
   ...

   public boolean processesEnclosingMethod() {
     if (fMethodStack.isEmpty())
        return false;
     return getEnclosingMethod() == fMethodStack.peek();
   }
}
```

For example, in case of `import java.util.Stack`, these lines used Java Util package:

```
 1- private Stack fMethodStack= new Stack();
 2- if (fMethodStack.isEmpty())
 3- return getEnclosingMethod() == fMethodStack.peek();
```

extra info 0: There might be many imports in a file so an efficient process is desired. Ignore the local packages.

extra info 1: If needed, the whole source code can be checked out (not just the file).

extra info 2: The commits arrive to a node running Python on Docker, so obviously IDE tool are not useful but I can run shell, Java commands or a parallel Java node if it would help.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is impossible, and you do not appear to understand how java works.

I better provide some details to back up that statement. I'll provide a few scenarios where what you want to do is not properly defined.

Imagine that exact, entirely identical file, except instead of an import statement plus `new Stack()`, the file contains no import statements whatsoever, and instead contains `new java.util.Stack()`. This file is valid java and is in fact 100% identical - same bytecode.

Or, even more complicated:

```
package a;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Somewhere {
  public static Stack makeStack() { return new Stack(); }
}
```

and then the target file you want to analyse looks like:

```
package b;
import a.Somewhere;

public class Example {
  public void method() {
    makeStack().isEmpty();
  }
}
```

Does this 'use' Stack? There is no import, whatsoever.

Or how about this one:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Example {
  void test() {
    var list = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println(list.toString());
  }
}
```

Does the call to `toString()` count? The signature is defined by `java.lang.Object`, but the implementation is provided by `java.util.ArrayList`. If you think that means it should 'count', note that it is impossible to know, that's the point of OO. You don't  care where the implementation is from, you just care that it exists.

A few notes if you really do want to continue down this crazy road:

1. You'd need a java parser that fully links all sources to get anywhere. This is incredibly complicated and requires quite some java expertise, even then, we're talking many weeks of development effort. You'd start with `javac` itself (which is GPL open source) or `ecj` (which MIT open source), and read up on how to get them to process those java files into Abstract Syntax Trees, attribute them, and then you could possibly do this job.
2. It's a lot easier to scan class files instead and simply look through the constant table for references to the types you are interested in. This makes `import` statements entirely irrelevant (In java, an `import` statement is just an aliasing. `import com.foo.Bar;` means: "Whenever `Bar` shows up anywhere in this source file in a place where a type is needed, assume that means `com.foo.Bar`. **An `import` statement in java does not run any code. It is *nothing* like python's `import` in any way.** This solution will find any invokes to anything defined in a type you're interested in, and will not find anything defined at a higher level (even if the implementation is provided by a type you're interested in), which follows how java is designed (which is: You can't care about who provides the implementation, it's literally not knowable in the vast majority of code cases unless you run it, and then you get into the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) if you want to do that kind of analysis). You can use BCEL, ASM, ByteBuddy, and a few other libraries to read class files.
3. You can chain these 2 things: Fetch some java files, compile them, then analyse the resulting class files using e.g. BCEL, ASM, ByteBuddy, yadayada.
4. Note that in python none of this is possible at all, as python is entirely dynamically typed. It is not possible to 'link' a method's name to an implementation or even a type, except using heuristics which are (by definition) unreliable. You *can* know this stuff if you run the code, but the Halting Problem would again ruin your day. In java a few interpretations of your question are at least possible, if difficult. (see #1).

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, 

Well, I guess it is way more difficult than what I expected as static code analysis.

How about me going one step back: Can I tell which lines used a package like "java.util Package" or is that also still very ambitious.

Keep in mind that I would not be able to build the project (sine not all commits would be buildable) so compiling is almost out of scope

Comment: We can ignore too complicated scenarios (such as the one that you provided for a hidden import from another file).

Comment: _which lines used a package like "java.util Package" or is that also still very ambitious._ - not possible without learning how to use ecj, javac, or any grammar parser that ships with a grammar for java (but note that just about all of them have  bugs, as the java grammar serves as example and wasn't intended for actual usage). You can then do your own import resolution which will fail for tricky star/local package scenarios but will do the right thing in 99% of the scenarios. But it won't catch `getList().size()` situations. analysing those class files is _a lot_ easier.

Comment: You misunderstand the 'hidden import' scenario. That scenario is __extremely common__ and has nothing to do with hidden imports. As I said, an import is simply an alias, and you can use types without importing them or even mentioning them. This happens all the time in java code. Disregarding that as 'complex' is crazy.

Comment: Alright, I can go in the direction of a grammar parser. But you are confirming that it is really possible to track-back to the line-by-line usage of a package. local packages are out of my scope I really just need any external package or jar that is used. I thought there should be an existing parser or technique in Java to do this already.

Comment: For example, (this is different of course) `javap ` can find methods in a jar file. Is there a parser to find which lines they are used in a source code?

Comment: There is no such parser, you need to attribute, which requires a complete compilation run. It's not a matter of 'keep looking for a parser', it's a matter of: What you want is __not possible__ without it. Without a full attribution, how could you possibly figure out which method `getFoo().getBar()` actually refers to? You'd have to know what the type of the `getFoo()` method is and what the signatures of the methods in that type are. If you know all that, you can do a full compilation run (thus, if you CANT do a full compile run, you clearly don't know that).